# How to call a named module from a bundle

Tags: ecmascript-6, systemjs

I have a project with ASP.NET 5 and TypeScript. basically this is my `wwwroot` folder

```
-wwwroot
|-app
||-person.js
||-employee.js
||-init.js
|-js
||-libraries.js    // Contains: systemjs, ...etc
||-app.bundle.js
```

`person.js` is an es6 module which exports `class Person`.

`employee.js` imports `person.js` and exports `class Employee`.

`init.js` just imports `employee.js`, creates a new `Employee` object and console his name.

```
//init.js
import { Employee } from "./employee";

var p = new Employee();
console.log(p.name);
```

Now I bundled the three files into `app.bundle.js` which is located in the `js` folder using `systemjs-builder` which produced three named `System.register` calls:

```
System.register("wwwroot/app/person.js",...
System.register("wwwroot/app/employee.js",...
System.register("wwwroot/app/init.js"...
```

In my `index.cshtml` view file I have these script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/libraries.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    System.config({
        packages: {
            js: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('js/app.bundle')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

apparently since I have named modules, whatever is in the `init.js` is not being called.

So my question is, how can I call a named `System.register` call ?

Note: I am new to es6 modules, so this is a test project to get the idea right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [wiki page](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md), I solved my problem with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    System.config({
        bundles: {
            'app.bundle.js': ['wwwroot/app/init']
        },
        packages: {
            wwwroot: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('wwwroot/app/init')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

To explain:

> The bundle extension will automatically download a bundle as soon as an attempt to import any module in that bundle is made.

So all I need to do is to tell `systemjs` to register the `init` module to my bundle and it will download the bundle and execute whatever is in the `init` module.